# Nginx reverse proxy to Apache2 +Wordpress not working

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, wordpress

**Wordpress site runs with apache2 its config:**

```
Listen 81
<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot /home/foo/public_html
    ServerName www.foo.fo
    ServerAlias foo.fo
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /home/foo/public_html>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Nginx configuration:**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name foo.fo, www.foo.fo;
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://172.17.4.19:81;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

Problem is that only index page are displayed. If navigating to another page, lets say **meniu-2**, then returns error 404.

apache2 access log

```
"GET /meniu-2/ HTTP/1.0" 404 463 "http://www.foo.fo/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

How to make this configuration to work?

Comment: You say manu-2 and access.log shows "/meniu-2/". Does that really exist?

Comment: Direct link is http://www.foo.fo/?page_id=3619. After it is opened in navigation bar http://www.foo.fo/meniu-2/ is shown. Manu-2 is my misspeling

Comment: Asking from curiosity; why do you have this setup?

Comment: Nginx is accessible from WAN and apache2+wordpress is in one container. Nginx should work as reverse proxy for this and many more like this linux containers